# Angular, input radio doesn't work with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, radio-button, nested, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have problem with ng-radio and nested ng-repeat. Plunker is [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/lQrnGP5xKSVEopEwHlZT?p=preview)

View:

```
    <div class="modal-header">
    <h3 ng-if="inquiry.name" class="modal-title">{{inquiry.name}}</h3>
    <h3 ng-if="!inquiry.name" class="modal-title">Add new inquiry</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading font-bold">Inquiry Questions</div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-condensed bg-white-only">
              <tbody>
                <tr style="font-weight: bold">
                  <th style="width:90%">Name
                  </th>
                  <th style="width:10%"></th>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="inquiry_question in inquiry.inquiry_questions">
                  <td class="v-middle">
                    <input type="text" min="0" class="form-control" id="productPrice" placeholder="Question name" ng-model="inquiry_question.name" />
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="radio">
                          <label class="i-checks">
                            <input type="radio" ng-attr-name="{{$index}}_type" ng-value="text" ng-model="inquiry_question.type" />
                            <i></i>
                            text
                          </label>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="radio">
                          <label class="i-checks">
                            <input type="radio" ng-attr-name="{{$index}}_type" ng-value="images" ng-model="inquiry_question.type" />
                            <i></i>
                            images
                          </label>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="radio">
                          <label class="i-checks">
                            <input type="radio" ng-attr-name="{{$index}}_form" ng-value="simple" ng-model="inquiry_question.form" />
                            <i></i>
                            single select
                          </label>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="radio">
                          <label class="i-checks">
                            <input type="radio" ng-attr-name="{{$index}}_form" ng-value="multiple" ng-model="inquiry_question.form" />
                            <i></i>
                            multiple points
                          </label>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                          <div class="panel-heading font-bold">Inquiry Answers</div>
                          <div class="panel-body">
                            <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-condensed bg-white-only">
                              <tbody>
                                <tr style="font-weight: bold">
                                  <th style="width:90%">Name
                                  </th>
                                  <th style="width:10%"></th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr ng-repeat="inquiry_question_answer in inquiry_question.inquiry_answers">
                                  <td class="v-middle">
                                    <div ng-if="inquiry_question.type=='text'">
                                      <input type="text" min="0" class="form-control" placeholder="Answer name" ng-model="inquiry_question_answer.name" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div ng-if="inquiry_question.type=='images'">
                                      <button ng-file-select="" ng-model="files.uploads" ng-if="!inquiry_question_answer.photo" ng-validui-jq="filestyle" class="btn-primary btn-sm btn-addon" ng-click="uploadHandler(inquiry_question_answer)">
                                        <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                                        Add inquiry photo answer
                                      </button>
                                      <div ng-if="inquiry_question_answer.photo">
                                        <div class="thumb-md">
                                          <img ng-src="../data/{{inquiry_question_answer.photo}}" alt="" />
                                        </div>
                                        <button ng-file-select="" ng-model="files.uploads" ng-validui-jq="filestyle" class="btn-primary btn-sm btn-addon" ng-click="uploadHandler(inquiry_question_answer)">
                                          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-repeat"></i>
                                          Change inquiry photo answer
                                        </button>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                  </td>
                                  <td style="white-space: nowrap">
                                    <div class="buttons">
                                      <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" ng-click="remove_inquiry_answer(inquiry_question.inquiry_answers,$index)">del
                                      </button>
                                    </div>
                                  </td>
                                </tr>
                              </tbody>
                            </table>
                            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-addon width-inherit" ng-click="add_inquiry_answer(inquiry_question.inquiry_answers)">
                              <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                              Add new answer
                            </button>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                  <td style="white-space: nowrap">
                    <div class="buttons">
                      <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" ng-click="remove_inquiry_question(inquiry.inquiry_questions,$index)">del
                      </button>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-addon width-inherit" ng-click="add_inquiry_question(inquiry.inquiry_questions)">
              <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
              Add new question
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Controller:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.inquiry = {
            inquiry_questions: [
                {
                    inquiry_answers:[]
                }
            ]
        };
    $scope.cancelInquiry = function () {
        $scope.inquiryFormShow = false;
    }

    $scope.add_inquiry_question = function (inquiry_questions) {
        inquiry_questions.push({name: "", type: "text", form: "multiple", inquiry_answers: []});
    }

    $scope.remove_inquiry_question = function (inquiry_questions,index) {
        inquiry_questions.splice(index, 1);
    };

    $scope.add_inquiry_answer = function (inquiry_answers) {
        inquiry_answers.push({name: ""});
    }

    $scope.remove_inquiry_answer = function (inquiry_answers, index) {
        inquiry_answers.splice(index, 1);
    };
});
```

Basically in ng-repeat ngmodel for these radio buttons seems unresponsive to any changes. As you can see in plunker after creating new question and selecting value in radio, this value is not respected by ng-if. If I prepopulate inquiry object from json all radio buttons are non selected even, if they have value in json. Ng model for text input works well.

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you should use ng-value with an angular expression rather than plain text, meaning, instead of using `ng-value="text"`, use a scope variable like:

```
$scope.textValue = 'text';
```

And bind the ng-value to that expression

```
ng-value="textValue"
```

Same goes for all other ng-values of course (images, single, multiple select)

Regarding the ng-ifs, it's just

```
ng-if="inquiry_question.type==='images'"
```

Instead of

```
ng-if="inquiry_question.type=='images'"
```

Here's a working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/WH3HgAVvs9gyICtTkD1g?p=preview).